# React-i18next - how to show keys

Tags: reactjs, react-i18next

Maybe it trivial but I didn't found how to do it in the docs -
Is there a way to configure the i18n to show the keys instead of the values?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to set the language to cimode: ?lng=cimode

Comment: Hi, is there a way to see the namespace next to the key?

Comment: appendNamespaceToCIMode: true   https://www.i18next.com/overview/configuration-options#others